# how to view the list of users who have access to a redshift table?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

How do i get a list of users who have access to a specific redshift table/schema?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a SQL gives you select/insert/update/delete privileges for each object

You can use schema, table, user filter while using/commenting the ones you don't at the end of the SQL.

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT 
            schemaname
            ,objectname
            ,usename
            ,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'select') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS sel
            ,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'insert') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS ins
            ,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'update') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS upd
            ,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'delete') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS del
            ,HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'references') AND has_schema_privilege(usrs.usename, schemaname, 'usage')  AS ref
        FROM
            (
            SELECT schemaname, 't' AS obj_type, tablename AS objectname, schemaname + '.' + tablename AS fullobj FROM pg_tables
            UNION
            SELECT schemaname, 'v' AS obj_type, viewname AS objectname, schemaname + '.' + viewname AS fullobj FROM pg_views
            ) AS objs
            ,(SELECT * FROM pg_user) AS usrs
        ORDER BY fullobj
        )
    WHERE (sel = true or ins = true or upd = true or del = true or ref = true)
    and usename = '<user>'.  -- for a user filter
    and schemaname = '<schema>'. -- for a schema filter
    and objectname = '<table or view>'. -- for a table filter
```

Output would look like this

```
schemaname          objectname          usename sel     ins     upd     del     ref
information_schema  applicable_roles    user1   true    false   false   false   false
information_schema  check_constraints   user1   true    false   false   false   false
information_schema  column_domain_usage user1   true    false   false   false   false
```

If you like to see only users with access to specifics schema/table use the required filter(s) and change the first line to

```
SELECT distinct usename
```

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL has something called System Information Functions, which you can read about here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-info.html

The function that could be of interest to you is `has_table_privilege`, which takes three arguments:

```
user
table name,
privelege
```

When I need to find out for example what roles can insert on my users table I execute the following:

```
SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles WHERE has_table_privilege(rolname, '<table_name>', 'INSERT')
```

However these functions in conjunction with tables `pg_roles`, `pg_user`, and other tables can give you very detailed information about privileges.

Also you didn't specify what kind of access (`INSERT`, `SELECT`, `DELETE`) but thanks to the third argument you can either combine it or get a list of users that have any.